# Displaying a DOM object content

Tags: javascript, dom

In one of my test units, I need to build a DOM object

```
describe('client/blog', () => {
  let htmlDoc;

  beforeEach(() => {
    htmlDoc = window.document;
  });

  it('set the DeletePostHandler', function () {
      var x = htmlDoc.createElement('p'); // Create a <p> element
      var t = htmlDoc.createTextNode('This is a paragraph.'); // Create a text node
      x.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <p>
      htmlDoc.body.appendChild(x);  
      console.log('DOM body: ', JSON.stringify(htmlDoc.body));
      ...
   });
   ...
});
```

but I cannot get the DOM body displayed in the console ...
what's the trick ?...

thanks for feedback

**UPDATE**

I tried :

```
console.log('DOM body: ', htmlDoc.body);
```

But I only get :

```
console.log tests/client/blog.spec.js:30
DOM body:  {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re your update: It sounds like you'll need to do a special function for your own purposes. `JSON.stringify` only does *own*, *enumerable* properties, which may be why you're not seeing what you want to see (many of the properties on DOM elements aren't own, enumerable properties; for instance, `innerHTML` isn't on Chrome).

One option is to log `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`, which will show you the contents of the element or the element along with its contents, as HTML:

```
console.log('DOM body: ', htmlDoc.body.innerHTML);
// or
console.log('DOM body: ', htmlDoc.body.outerHTML);
```

If you want to do something more tailored, you (presumably) have the full power of the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) available to you...

Comment: yes.. you're right ... as I am using Jest framework , I have access to the DOM (JSDom is available in Jest ) ... there is a good exemple in Jest doc   at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery

Answer (score 1):

To view a DOM node in the console, don't try to stringify it. Just log the variable itself.

```
console.log('DOM body: ', htmlDoc.body);
```

Comment: ^^ That way, the console can do smart things (and on a decent browser, it does -- for instance, on Chrome, it shows you the element much as it would in the Elements panel, and if the element is in the DOM, offers a right-click menu item to take you to the element in the Elements panel).

Comment: Thanks @Hydrothermal, I already tried it but it does not display it ... or the body Is empty and my coding is wrong ...  see UPDATE in my question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder.  I am in test unit , so I don't display in a browser,  console.log() is in my tests file.